# "Subset" List Coloring for Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, coloring

I am interested in the following problem for research: we are given a graph $G$ and two integers $N, d$ with $N \ge d$.

Say that $G$ is "$(N,d)$-subset-list colorable" if each vertex $v$ is assigned a subset $s(v)$ of $\{1, ..., N\}$, and for each edge $uv$, the symmetric difference of $s(u)$ and $s(v)$ has size at least $d$.

When $d=1$, of course we can apply any known "standard list coloring" algorithm by letting the lists that can be chosen be every subset of $\{1, ..., N\}$, i.e., each vertex "color" is a subset of $\{1,...,N\}$.

Has this problem been studied before? Simple Google Scholar searches has not turned up anything. If not, is there a nontrivial exact algorithm? General bounds? I'm interested for when $d$ is fixed and finding the smallest $N$ for which $G$ is $(N,d)$-subset-list colorable.

Comment: Would it be much more interesting if the constraint is relaxed to values smaller than $d$? It is not immediate to me whether we have equivalent "near-bipartite" definitions.

Comment: Huh? The symmetric difference the sets $s(u)$ and $s(v)$ is a **set**, and $d$ is a **number**. What does "$X$ is at least $d$" mean if $X$ is a set and $d$ is a number?

Comment: @MishaLavrov My mistake. Missed a parameter. And yes I meant the symmetric difference size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like many coloring variants, this problem can be phrased as a [graph homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_homomorphism) problem. Let $H_{N,d}$ be the graph whose vertices are subsets of $\{1,\dots,N\}$, with an edge between two subsets if and only if the symmetric difference between them has size at least $d$. Then a graph $G$ is $(N,d)$-subset-list colorable if and only if there is a graph homomorphism $G \to H_{N,d}$. Determining if $G$ has a homomorphism to a fixed graph $H$ is also called the "$H$-coloring problem", so here, we are faced with the $H_{N,d}$-coloring problem.

*By the way, the term "subset-list colorable" is misleading; list-colorability is a different, and unrelated problem. I think "$(N,d)$-subset colorable" would be equally distinguishing, and less confusing.*

What does the graph homomorphism terminology gain us? Well, we can say the following:

- By the Hell–Nešetřil theorem, if a fixed graph $H$ is not bipartite, the $H$-coloring problem is NP-complete. In particular, this problem is NP-complete except in the case $N=d$.
- A graph $G$ is $k$-colorable in the ordinary sense if there is a graph homomorphism $G \to K_k$. Therefore if $H_{N,d}$ is $k$-colorable, then every $H_{N,d}$-colorable graph is also $k$-colorable, by composing the homomorphisms. As a result, if you compute $\chi(H_{N,d})$ in terms of $N$ and $d$, you will learn some necessary conditions for $H_{N,d}$-colorability of $G$ in terms of $\chi(G)$.
- The [core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_(graph_theory)) of a graph $H$ is the smallest induced subgraph $C$ of $H$ with a homomorphism $H \to C$. There is also a homomorphism $C \to H$, so $C$ and $H$ are homomorphically equivalent: checking if a graph is $H$-colorable can be simplified to checking if it is $C$-colorable. It is worth checking if $H_{N,d}$ ever has a nontrivial core, which would simplify the problem.

As an example, $H_{3,2}$ (the first case with $1 < d < N$) is the complement of the cube graph. It is $4$-colorable (give $(x,y,0)$ and $(x,y,1)$ the same color for all $x,y$), so every graph that is $H_{3,2}$-colorable is also $4$-colorable. On the other hand, $K_4$ is $H_{3,2}$-colorable (label the $4$ vertices $(0,0,0)$, $(0,1,1)$, $(1,0,1)$, and $(1,1,0)$), so every $4$-colorable graph is $H_{3,2}$-colorable. This reveals that $K_4$ is the core of $H_{3,2}$, and that the $H_{3,2}$-coloring problem is equivalent to the standard $4$-coloring problem.

This kind of reduction happens whenever the chromatic number and the clique number of $H_{N,d}$ are equal. Experimentally, it looks like $H_{N,2}$ in general has both chromatic number and clique number equal to $2^{N-1}$; if that's true, it would imply $H_{N,2}$-coloring is equivalent to standard $2^{N-1}$-coloring. However, $H_{4,3}$ has chromatic number $4$ and clique number $2$, so $H_{4,3}$-coloring is not equivalent to any standard $k$-coloring problem.

Comment: Thank you very much!